# Why does start command in cmd windows10 put another start in the newly opened window with php?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, php, localhost

What I was trying to do is, I want to run a local php server and then open `http://localhost:8000` in chrome. I made a bat file in my windows 10 OS for this. Here's my first attempt:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox 
http://localhost:8000
```

The problem with this was after the first line is executed the cmd get stuck in a loop of listening to the server and the second line never gets execute. Plus, I don't want to open localhost webpage first because it keep showing the error for a few secs untill php does it's thing. Now the solution I found was the following bat file:

```
start php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox 
start http://localhost:8000
```

This does the job, but I saw a weird behaviour. I expected the first line to open a new cmd window and execute `php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox`, but what it does is, it opens a new cmd window and executes this `start php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox`. This opens php's own shell(which has a php logo) and then goes on to execute `-S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox` in that new console.

1. If I do `start php` in cmd, it opens the php shell. Then, if I go `-S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox` inside that php shell, it doesn't open local server, why?
2. When I run the bat file why doesn't `start` opens a new cmd window and puts `php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox` and keep the cmd window? Instead why does it put `start php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox` in that new `cmd` window, exits and opens php shell?
3. Is there any way to keep the server running in cmd window and then somehow open the localhost webpage?

Comment: Please read [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and look at the syntax of `start`.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I have, this one, `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`. I assume it takes `php` as command to execute with `-S localhost...` as parameters. But, then if I run `php -S localhost...` straightaway in cmd why doesn't it open the php shell then?

Comment: I've no idea. I don't use php.

Comment: That's alright, bloke.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use 1st in backgound?

**`start "" /b`**

---

```bat
@echo off

rem :: use cd /d path to php

cd /d "c:\php"
start "" /b php -S localhost:8000 -t C:\User\Projects\Sandbox 
start "" http://localhost:8000
```

Take a look **[here about multi session in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)**

Comment: Could you elaborate on how `/b` flag stops the php shell, how does it start the server in the background, then switch to second start localhost statement and then brings back the background running server to the main cmd window?

Comment: @user31782  forgive me se. I think you may need a new question, change the scope from original question is not allowed.

Comment: Would you be able to answer #1 and #2 of my question?

Comment: @user31782  Well, i'll try for sure...

Comment: Maybe not sure also, if will be only bat (100% pure bat), or (hybrid with vbs+bat/powershell+bat )

Comment: I just use cmd in windows10. I have just one file named `server.bat` with them two commands.

Comment: If I can not to do this, I'm sure that someone will. But, can take a time for this user (not me) came see the question and answer...

Comment: That's alright mate. Thanks.